# DataReader returns no rows -- rows are present in database

Tags: c#, .net, mysql, ado.net, datareader

Okay world, I'm having some trouble. No, this is not 'homework'

I've got some code which needs to do two things:
1) Read a list of artists from a database
2) Find all tracks written by that artist and store it for later

What I'm doing:
1) `SELECT ArtistID FROM artists` gets me my list of artists. I build it up in a `List<string>` datatype, using a `DataReader`, etc. works great
2) `SELECT count(*) as track_numbers from tracks WHERE ArtistID = @ArtistID` does not work so great

**My problem**:
The second select statement will succeed if I manually specify the `ArtistID` (ie: `SELECT count(*) as track_numbers FROM Tracks WHERE ArtistID = 0` works) but if I am iterating through my list, it will always return zero results.

I am using *Connector/Net 6.3.6*, *Visual Studio 2010* (all updates), *.NET 4.0 Client Profile*, *MySQL Community Server 5.5.9 x64*, *Windows 7 Home Premium x64*

I have tried:

- Using string concatenation to build up my query string with the artistid
- casting artistid as a string, then an int, then vice-versa
- re-arranging where the parameters are defined, the value put in, the command text

Relevant (I think) code below:

```
List<string> list = new List<string>();
Hashtable table = new Hashtable();
DbProviderFactory factory = DbProviderFactories.GetFactory(setting.ProviderName);
using (DbConnection conn = factory.CreateConnection())
{
conn.ConnectionString = setting.ConnectionString;
conn.Open();

using (DbCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
{
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT ArtistID FROM artists;";
    using (DbDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
    {
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            list.Add(reader["ArtistID"].ToString()); //this works, and I can iterate no problem through this list
        }
    }
}

using (DbCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
{
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT count(*) as counts FROM tracks WHERE ArtistID = @ArtistID;";
    //cmd.CommandText = "SELECT count(*) as counts FROM tracks WHERE ArtistID = 0;"; <-- this line works


    DbParameter param = cmd.CreateParameter();
    param.ParameterName = "@ArtistID";

    foreach (string artist in list)
    {
        param.Value = artist;
        cmd.Parameters.Add(param);
        using (DbDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                Console.WriteLine(artist + "\t" + reader["counts"]); //reader["counts"] is always '0'
            }
            cmd.Parameters.Clear();
        }
    }
}
```

}

The database table format is: 
Artist has one value/key called `ArtistID`, type `int`
Tracks has three columns, `TrackID (int, pk)`, `artistid (int)`, `albumid(int)`

Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: Can you check `HasRows` property before you start the loop? and see if retrieval is actually working or something wrong at the data source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to remove the `cmd.Parameters.Add(param);` call.  That adds a new parameter on each iteration.  It should be sufficient to just set the parameter value each time for the existing parameter.

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach (string artist in list)
{
    param.Value = artist;
    cmd.Parameters.Add(param)
```

You are currently re-adding the parameter for every artist - I'm surprised that this works at all, certainly it shouldn't for `SqlParameter` - if `DbParameter` works the same way it should be like this:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add(param);
foreach (string artist in list)
{
    param.Value = artist;
```

Answer (score 0):

After smashing my head against the wall for another hour, I discovered the problem: 
1) I needed to do a 'clean solution' for reasons I cannot fathom 
2) Somehow the foreign key relationships ensuring that there actually was an artistid in tracks that matched an artistid in artists I had somehow managed to screw up

I am in fact a huge idiot.

The above answers while not they did not fix my problem, did teach me something new about c#, so I'm giving credit to the 1st poster.